# 2D Positioning with the adafruit imbue

Tags: arduino, sensor, raspberry-pi

Is there a way to get x and y coordinates from the adafruit BN0055 IMU. Im trying to use 2D positional tracking to see how far a robot travels using this. I don't want to just use encoders because if the robot gets stuck along its path i won't be able to go an exact distance. I also plan to use it to make an automated way to shoot balls into a hoop after they have been collected (i can automate the power of the shooter so that i can shoot from anywhere)

Comment: If not the BN0055 then any sensor that is completely independent of itself like the BN0055

Answer (score 0):

No. The BN0055 can only sense orientation and acceleration -- it does not, and cannot, track its position.

Comment: In theory, if you know the acceleration of an object, and its starting position, you can calculate its movement by integrating the acceleration to get velocity and then integrating the velocity to get distance and hence location.  This is how inertial navigation systems aboard nuclear submarines operate. In practice, errors can quickly build up due to offsets and inaccuracies in the input data. Whether it would work for your application depends on the allowable position error and for how long the system needs to operate as the errors increase with time.

Comment: @Barry Correct, that is possible. (For the OP: this technique is typically known as "inertial dead reckoning".) However, _the BN0055 doesn't implement that_; it's only possible with additional logic in a host device.

Comment: Do you know of a sensor that can achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: @ArchishmaanP A GPS receiver.

Comment: but thats not completely independent is it it need a transmitter or is just one unit that i put in and can read data from it?

Comment: @ArchishmaanP The 'transmitters' are GPS satellites. They've already been set up. ;)

Comment: hmm but the resolution would not be very high I'm looking of within a centimeter